# How make many form into same page

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I want to embed two forms in the same page. When validating form 1, it also inserts the values from form 2. This is not what I want.

I want that when validating form 1, it inserts the data on the property concerned and not on

Both forms use the same FormType

**Controller :**

```php
$form_popup = $this->createForm(MetaType::class, $popup);
$form_topbar = $this->createForm(MetaType::class, $topbar_title);

if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {

    $form_popup->handleRequest($request);
    $form_topbar->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form_popup->isSubmitted()) {
        // Handle $form1
        $metasService->updatePopup($form_popup, $popup, $id);

    } else if ($form_topbar->isSubmitted()) {
        // Handle $form2
        $metasService->updatePopup($form_topbar, $topbar_title, $id);
    }
```

**Service :**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Service;

use App\Repository\MetaRepository;
use App\Repository\WidgetsRepository;
use App\Repository\LibWidgetsRepository;

use App\Form\MetaType;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;

class MetasService
{

   protected $requestStack;
   protected $security;
   protected $router;
   protected $metaRepository;
   protected $widgetsRepository;
   protected $libWidgetsRepository;

   public function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack, Security $security, UrlGeneratorInterface $router, MetaRepository $metaRepository, WidgetsRepository $widgetsRepository, LibWidgetsRepository $libWidgetsRepository)
   {
      $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
      $this->security = $security;
      $this->router = $router;
      $this->metaRepository = $metaRepository;
      $this->widgetsRepository = $widgetsRepository;
      $this->libWidgetsRepository = $libWidgetsRepository;
   }

   public function updatePopup($form_popup, $popup, $id) {
         $this->metaRepository->add($popup);

         $session = $this->requestStack->getSession();
         $session->getFlashBag()->add('success', 'La popup a bien été mis à jour !');

         
         return $this->router->generate('app_overlay_show', ['id' => $id], Response::HTTP_SEE_OTHER);
   }
 
}
```

**FormType :**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Meta;
use App\Entity\Widgets;

use App\Repository\WidgetsRepository;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class MetaType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('MetaKey',  null, array(
                'attr' => array(
                    'placeholder' => 'hereYourPlaceHolder'
                )
           ))
            ->add('MetaValue',  null, array(
                'attr' => array(
                    'placeholder' => 'hereYourPlaceHolder'
                )
           ))
            ->add('Widgets')
            ->add('userId')
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Meta::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

**Twig template :**

```
{{ form_start(form_popup) }}

{% if form_errors(form_popup) %}
    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
        {{ form_errors(form_popup) }}
    </div>
{% endif %}

{% if app.request.attributes.get('_route') == 'app_meta_new' %}
    <div class="input-grp">
        <h3>Clé/Valeur</h3>
        <p>Renseignez une clé unique pour cette métadonnée afin de pouvoir l'appeler sur votre overlay ainsi que de renseigner sa valeur.</p>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                    {{ form_widget(form_popup.MetaKey, {
        'attr': {'class': 'form-control'},
        'id': "MetaKey",
        }) }}
                    {{ form_label(form_popup.MetaKey, null, {
    'label': 'Définissez le nom de votre métadonnée',
    'id': 'MetaKey'
        }) }}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                    {{ form_widget(form_popup.MetaValue, {
        'attr': {'class': 'form-control'},
        'id': "MetaValue",
        }) }}
                    {{ form_label(form_popup.MetaValue, null, {
    'label': 'Définissez la valeur de votre métadonnée',
    'id': 'MetaValue'
        }) }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="input-grp-center">
        <h3>Associer à un widget</h3>
        <p>Si vous voulez que cette métadonnée soit associé à un widget, veuillez sélectionner le widget ci-dessous</p>
        <div class="form-floating mb-3">
            {{ form_widget(form_popup.Widgets, {
                                                'attr': {'class': 'form-select'},
                                                'id': "Widgets",
                                                }) }}
            {{ form_label(form_popup.Widgets, null, {
                                'label': 'Sélectionnez le widget',
                                'id': 'Widgets'
                                                }) }}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endif %}

{% if app.request.attributes.get('_route') == 'app_meta_edit' or app.request.attributes.get('_route') == 'app_overlay_show' %}
    <div class="input-grp">
        <h3>Valeur</h3>
        <p>Renseignez une clé unique pour cette métadonnée afin de pouvoir l'appeler sur votre overlay ainsi que de renseigner sa valeur.</p>
        <div class="form-floating mb-3">
            {{ form_widget(form_popup.MetaValue, {
        'attr': {'class': 'form-control'},
        'id': "MetaValue",
        }) }}
            {{ form_label(form_popup.MetaValue, null, {
    'label': 'Définissez la valeur de votre métadonnée',
    'id': 'MetaValue'
        }) }}

            {{ form_widget(form_popup.MetaKey, {
        'attr': {'class': 'display_none'},
        'id': "MetaKey",
        }) }}
            {{ form_label(form_popup.MetaKey, null, {
    'label_attr': {'class': 'display_none'},
    }) }}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endif %}




{{ form_label(form_popup.userId, null, {
    'label_attr': {'class': 'display_none'},
    }) }}
{{ form_widget(form_popup.userId, {
        'attr': {
            'class': 'display_none',
            },
        }) }}


<button class="btn btn-success">
    <span class="iconify" data-icon="fluent:save-arrow-right-20-filled"></span>
    {{ button_label|default('Créer la métadonnée') }}</button>
{{ form_end(form_popup) }}
```

```
{{ form_start(form_topbar) }}

{% if form_errors(form_topbar) %}
    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
        {{ form_errors(form_topbar) }}
    </div>
{% endif %}

{% if app.request.attributes.get('_route') == 'app_meta_new' %}
    <div class="input-grp">
        <h3>Clé/Valeur</h3>
        <p>Renseignez une clé unique pour cette métadonnée afin de pouvoir l'appeler sur votre overlay ainsi que de renseigner sa valeur.</p>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                    {{ form_widget(form_topbar.MetaKey, {
        'attr': {'class': 'form-control'},
        'id': "MetaKey",
        }) }}
                    {{ form_label(form_topbar.MetaKey, null, {
    'label': 'Définissez le nom de votre métadonnée',
    'id': 'MetaKey'
        }) }}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                    {{ form_widget(form_topbar.MetaValue, {
        'attr': {'class': 'form-control'},
        'id': "MetaValue",
        }) }}
                    {{ form_label(form_topbar.MetaValue, null, {
    'label': 'Définissez la valeur de votre métadonnée',
    'id': 'MetaValue'
        }) }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="input-grp-center">
        <h3>Associer à un widget</h3>
        <p>Si vous voulez que cette métadonnée soit associé à un widget, veuillez sélectionner le widget ci-dessous</p>
        <div class="form-floating mb-3">
            {{ form_widget(form_topbar.Widgets, {
                                                'attr': {'class': 'form-select'},
                                                'id': "Widgets",
                                                }) }}
            {{ form_label(form_topbar.Widgets, null, {
                                'label': 'Sélectionnez le widget',
                                'id': 'Widgets'
                                                }) }}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endif %}

{% if app.request.attributes.get('_route') == 'app_meta_edit' or app.request.attributes.get('_route') == 'app_overlay_show' %}
    <div class="input-grp">
        <h3>Valeur</h3>
        <p>Renseignez une clé unique pour cette métadonnée afin de pouvoir l'appeler sur votre overlay ainsi que de renseigner sa valeur.</p>
        <div class="form-floating mb-3">
            {{ form_widget(form_topbar.MetaValue, {
        'attr': {'class': 'form-control'},
        'id': "MetaValue",
        }) }}
            {{ form_label(form_topbar.MetaValue, null, {
    'label': 'Définissez la valeur de votre métadonnée',
    'id': 'MetaValue'
        }) }}

            {{ form_widget(form_topbar.MetaKey, {
        'attr': {'class': 'display_none'},
        'id': "MetaKey",
        }) }}
            {{ form_label(form_topbar.MetaKey, null, {
    'label_attr': {'class': 'display_none'},
    }) }}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endif %}



{{ form_label(form_topbar.userId, null, {
    'label_attr': {'class': 'display_none'},
    }) }}
{{ form_widget(form_topbar.userId, {
        'attr': {
            'class': 'display_none',
            },
        }) }}


<button class="btn btn-success">
    <span class="iconify" data-icon="fluent:save-arrow-right-20-filled"></span>
    {{ button_label|default('Créer la métadonnée') }}</button>
{{ form_end(form_topbar) }}
```

Comment: Can you show us the `MetaType` and both form twig templates?

Comment: Each form is self contained with their own submit button?  Might be easier to understand what is going on by having each form POST to a different controller action.  That should get rid of any possible interactions between the two forms when processing.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why both forms are submitted is that form fields names are the same. You would have to create two forms with different names. Eg.

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormFactoryInterface;

...

public function someAction(Request $request, FormFactoryInterface $formFactory, ...){
    $form_popup = $formFactory->createNamed('popup', MetaType::class, $popup);
    $form_topbar = $formFactory->createNamed('topbar', MetaType::class, $topbar_title);
    ...
}
```

PS: there are also some other things which would be good to improve. Eg. why do you have to twigs when the only difference is name of the form? It's absolutely redundant.